# Processing SFTP files using C# Parallel.ForEach loop not processing downloads

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, parallel.foreach, ssh.net

I am using the Renci SSH.NET package version 2016. I am downloading files from an external server. I usually can download about one file every 6 seconds which is bad when you have thousands of files. **I recently tried to change the `foreach` loops to `Parallel.ForEach`**. Doing that changed the files downloaded times to 1.5 seconds. Except when I checked the files they all had 0 KB's so it did not download anything. Is there anything wrong with the parallel loop? I am new to C# and trying to improve download times

```
Parallel.ForEach(summary.RemoteFiles, (f, loopstate) =>
{
    //Are we still connected? If not, reestablish a connection for up to a max of "MaxReconnectAttempts" 
    if (!sftp.IsConnected)
    {
        int maxAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxReconnectAttempts"]);

        StatusUpdate(this, new Types.StatusUpdateEventArgs() { message = "SFTP Service has been connected from remote system, attempting to reconnect (" + sftpConnInfo.Host + ":" + sftpConnInfo.Port.ToString() + remotePath + " - Attempt 1 of " + maxAttempts.ToString() + ")", Location = locationName });

        for (int attempts = 1; attempts <= maxAttempts; attempts++)
        {
            sftp.Connect();

            if (sftp.IsConnected)
            {
                StatusUpdate(this, new Types.StatusUpdateEventArgs() { message = "SFTP Service - Connection reestablished (" + remotePath + ")", Location = locationName });
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((attempts + 1) <= maxAttempts)
                {
                    StatusUpdate(this, new Types.StatusUpdateEventArgs() { message = "SFTP Service still disconnected from remote system, preparing another reconnect attempt (" + sftpConnInfo.Host + ":" + sftpConnInfo.Port.ToString() + remotePath + " - Attempt " + (attempts + 1).ToString() + " of " + maxAttempts.ToString() + ")", Location = locationName });
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Max reconnect attempts reached - end the session and ensure the appropriate "failure" workflow is triggered
                    connectionLost = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (connectionLost)
        loopstate.Break();
       // break;


    totalFileCount++;
    try
    {
      if (!System.IO.File.Exists(localSaveLocation + f.FileName))

        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tDownloading file " + totalFileCount.ToString() + "(" + f.FileName + ")");

            System.IO.Stream localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localSaveLocation + f.FileName);
            //Log remote file name, local file name, date/time start
            start = DateTime.Now;
            sftp.DownloadFile(f.FullName, localFile);
            end = DateTime.Now;

            //Log remote file name, local file name, date/time complete (increment the "successful" downloads by 1)
            timeElapsed = end.Subtract(start);
            runningSeconds += timeElapsed.TotalSeconds;
            runningAvg = runningSeconds / Convert.ToDouble(totalFileCount);
            estimatedSecondsRemaining = (summary.RemoteFiles.Count - totalFileCount) * runningAvg;

            elapsedTimeString = timeElapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("#.####") + " seconds";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tCompleted downloading file in " + elapsedTimeString + " " + "(" + f.FileName + ")");
            downloadedFileCount++;
            ProcessFileComplete(this, new Types.ProcessFileCompleteEventArgs() { downloadSuccessful = true, elapsedTime = timeElapsed.TotalSeconds, fileName = f.FileName, fullLocalPath = localSaveLocation + f.FileName, Location = locationName, FilesDownloaded = totalFileCount, FilesRemaining = (summary.RemoteFiles.Count - totalFileCount), AvgSecondsPerDownload = runningAvg, TotalSecondsElapsed = runningSeconds, EstimatedTimeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(estimatedSecondsRemaining) });

            f.FileDownloaded = true;

            if (deleteAfterDownload)
                sftp.DeleteFile(f.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tFile " + totalFileCount.ToString() + "(" + f.FileName + ") already exists locally");
            downloadedFileCount++;

            ProcessFileComplete(this, new Types.ProcessFileCompleteEventArgs() { downloadSuccessful = true, elapsedTime = 0, fileName = f.FileName + " (File already exists locally)", fullLocalPath = localSaveLocation + f.FileName, Location = locationName, FilesDownloaded = totalFileCount, FilesRemaining = (summary.RemoteFiles.Count - totalFileCount), AvgSecondsPerDownload = runningAvg, TotalSecondsElapsed = runningSeconds, EstimatedTimeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(estimatedSecondsRemaining) });
            f.FileDownloaded = true;

            if (deleteAfterDownload)
                sftp.DeleteFile(f.FullName);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
       // We log stuff here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot tell why you get empty file. Though I'd suspect the fact that you do not close the `localFile` stream.

Though, even if your code worked, you will get hardly any performance benefit if you use the same connection for the downloads, as SFTP transfers tend to be limited by a network latency or CPU. You have to use multiple connections to overcome that.

See my [answer on Server Fault about factors that affect SFTP transfer speed](https://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875#694063).

Implement some connection pool and pick a free connection each time.

---

Simple example:

```
var clients = new ConcurrentBag<SftpClient>();

var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConnections };

Parallel.ForEach(files, opts, (f, loopstate) => {
    if (!clients.TryTake(out var client))
    {
        client = new SftpClient(hostName, userName, password);
        client.Connect();
    }

    string localPath = Path.Combine(destPath, f.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Thread {0}, Connection {1}, File {2} => {3}",
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, client.GetHashCode(),
        f.FullName, localPath);

    using (var stream = File.Create(localPath))
    {
        client.DownloadFile(f.FullName, stream);
    }

    clients.Add(client);
});

Console.WriteLine("Closing {0} connections", clients.Count);

foreach (var client in clients)
{
    client.Dispose();
}
```

---

Another approach is to start a fixed number of threads with one connection for each and have them pick files from a queue.

For an example of implementation see my article for WinSCP .NET assembly:
[Automating transfers in parallel connections over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers)

---

*A similar question about FTP:*
*[Download multiple files concurrently from FTP using FluentFTP with a maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66241158/850848)*